Adding a transparent x-infinite but y-limited shaded area to lightweight charts in Vue.js (draw transparent rectangle simply put)
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lightweight-charts-skeleton-forked-jwdjh5
Hi everyone, I need to create a bottom border for a rectangle. The rectangle is an areaSeries (I mean), and I've set the top boundary, but I can't figure out how to set the bottom boundary. Does anyone have an idea of how I can do this? Right now, the lower boundary has an infinite y value. At picture u can see infinity bottom border (check right bar)

I want something like 

As it stands it's not really clear what you're asking for. Can you clarify? Or maybe show a picture with the desired outcome?

edited this question
